# How to open recent project in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, workspace

I have couple of android projects, where I have to switch between them very often. I was searching in `Android Studio` for recent projects option to switch between projects, but I didn't find one. In `eclipse` we have switch work-space option, is there any similar functionality available in Android Studio?

*Eclipse Image*

[image: eclipse switch workspace]

Comment: In recent android studio versions it's now `File -> Open Recent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Files` then `Reopen Projects`.
IF you can't do that restart Android Studio or the reason that you have only ONE project.

Comment: some how Studio forgets my other projects,  as you said.if two or more projects are there, then Reopen Projects will be enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Check Files->Reopen Projects.... You could find all your recent projects... You could open Two projects at a time and switch between windows as per your needs.